# How can you get the analogue sensor data into Max MSP?

Tags: arduino, maxmsp

How can you get the analogue sensor data into Max MSP with an Arduino?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Atleast [Arduino2Max](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Interfacing/MaxMSP) allows you to read analogue pins and also digital pins into a Max.

Answer (score 5):

While doing some surfing trying to find out more about Max MSP, I came across this site:

http://file-error.net/1o1o1o1o1/?Physical_Computing_and_Interaction:Arduino:Arduino_VS_Max/MSP

The Arduino2Max section of the page (near the bottom) has a patch for Max MSP and some sample code for the Arduino.  I don't know if that helps, because I don't have Max MSP available, but maybe it'll get the ball rolling.

Answer (score 5):

This is a particularly clean implementation for automagic analog and digital input with some built-in code for using a 4051 multiplexer on the analog pins:

[SensorBox](http://pixlpa.com/blog/arduino-sensorbox-firmware) by Andrew Benson
(via [C74 forum](http://cycling74.com/forums/topic.php?id=22767#post-116559))

Answer (score 3):

Send/print the analogue pin data to Arduino's serial monitor, then use MAX MSP's serial object to recieve it. It's quite simple, no externals are required. Make sure you specify arguments to select the appropriate channel and Baud rate to match your Arduino.

Have fun!